# Sublime text 2 control package does not show

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have installed Sublime Text 2. I did as shown in the image. It is supposed to have `Preferences -> PackageControl`. But its not there.

I have tried many times to install and uninstall, but control package is not there. Is there anyone can help me out of this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You are using linux or windows ??

Comment: Is there some reason why you want Sublime Text 2 instead of 3? V2 was last updated in July 2013. V3 has been the default download version on the web site for quite some time and is superior in many ways. [See this post by wbond](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/3), he is the developer of PackageControl and [he now works for Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3103). V3 may technically be in beta but it is totally stable, I suggest you install that instead unless you have some compelling reason not to.

Comment: BTW with ST 3 there is a menu item to install *Package Control*, in the *Tools* menu I think (it is not shown if it is already installed so I can not check).

Comment: problem resolved.. thanks